# Installing node-curl On Heroku

Tags: node.js, curl, heroku, dependencies, npm

**Full Disclaimer** this Works on my local machine Mac OSX 10.9.5. I've installed the package locally by using npm install ... But when I push up to the heroku server I get the error message:

```
gyp ERR! build error
...
npm ERR! Failed at the node-curl@0.3.3 install script 'sh src/generate_curl_options_list.sh && (node-gyp rebuild || node-waf configure build)'.
...
push rejected to yzx.xyz
```

When I omit the node-curl module dependency in my config.json, I am able to push:

```
"dependencies": {
        "node-curl": "0.3.3",
        ...
}
```

Unfortunately my code relies on the above library:

```
var Curl = require('node-curl/lib/Curl');
```

May be related to to this [issue](https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl/issues/1) or possibly this [issue](https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl/issues/19). My thoughts are the heroku server running ubuntu is not compatible with this library or the version of node-curl. Also I have found in my research the lib-curl package needs to be installed on the host. Is there a way to install libcurl3-dev on Heroku? or is there another node-curl library I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to upgrade my node and npm engine:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.8",
    "npm":"1.4.x"
  },
```

Did the trick

Comment: As a sidenote, I ended up using npm request for all of my needs. I come from a PHP background so CURL made sense. Turns out I didnt need curl at all.